# How to read profile results of PostgreSQL JIT

Tags: postgresql, llvm, perf

According to docs of PostgreSQL, turning **jit_profiling_support** to on, PostgreSQL generate the data to allow to perf.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-developer.html

> If LLVM has the required functionality, emit the data needed to allow perf to profile functions generated by JIT. This writes out files to $HOME/.debug/jit/;

Now I set **jit_profiling_support** to on and execute some queries.

```
testdb=# show jit_profiling_support;
 jit_profiling_support 
-----------------------
 on
(1 row)
```

Certainly, it generates the file to $HOME/.debug/jit/.

```
/home/postgres/.debug/jit/llvm-IR-jit-20191216-a64065:
total 12
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Dec 16 13:47 .
drwx------ 12 postgres postgres 4096 Dec 17 14:08 ..
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 2030 Dec 16 13:47 jit-3880.dump
```

However, I can't this dump file. I tried to read with perf, but failed (as below).

```
$ perf report -v -i /home/postgres/.debug/jit/llvm-IR-jit-20191216-a64065/jit-3880.dump
magic/endian check failed
incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)
```

How can I read this file?

Comment: As far as I understand it, this is not `perf` ouput, but data required so that `perf` can profile PostgreSQL. For example, you should now see more if you run `perf top`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing "perf inject" to get symbols in "perf report".

> perf inject -j -i perf.data -o perf.jitted.data
>
> perf report -i perf.jitted.data

This should work.

**More details**: PostgreSQL uses LLVM compiler suite for JIT. The suite generates code at runtime, also dumps symbols information in binary data file ending with *.dump under *JITDUMPDIR* directory. The perf tool consumes these symbols during inject step to display correct profiling info.